# Save and Load PivotTable configuration at runtime

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm looking for a way to save and load the entire Excel pivot table configuration using VBA. I'd like to have several layouts(ie. grouping, columns, filters, etc) for a single pivot table that would be selectable from a combo box. Is there something like that already written?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I intend to put into a commercial PivotTable addin I'm working on (but I haven't coded it up yet). Basically the way to achieve this most simply is to simply store a copy of each of the the PivotTable configurations you want on a hidden sheet, and when the user selects the one they want from a dropdown simply swap it for the one currently viewable.